# Problem with zero-width space in TeX Live 2015

Tags: texstudio, texworks

Unfortunately I can’t enter a  [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) via keyboard shortcuts in TeX Live 2015, neither in TeXworks editor nor in TexStudio. I didn’t have this problem in TeX Live 2014.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
:(نمیخواهم
:(نمی خواهم
:)می‌خواهم
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you be more specific?  "can't use" does not give us any clues, do you get an error or the wrong output or... I ran your document without error in texlive 2015 updated today, but I can not read the script so I can not verify the output unless you describe or show a screenshot for good output and bad output

Comment: No error, no wrong output!
I can’t do that!
For example, I can insert **zero-width space character** with _Shift+Space_ key (I use **Persian Standard Keyboard**) in _Microsoft Office, WordPad, Notepad_ and so on, but I can’t do that in _TeXworks_ editor :(
I made the above example script with _Notepad_ not with _TeXworks_ :)
In addition, I’ve tried every possible key combination _(Shift+B, Ctrl+Shift+2, …)_ in _TeXworks_, but it doesn’t work.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Oh! In that case it is not a tex question at all really, someone may be able to help (sorry I can not but I do not have that editor) but it is probably better to ask editor specific questions on the support lists for that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known Qt Bug. See:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-42074

https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1127/

Comment: I installed back, TeXworks version 0.4.5 (with Qt v4.8.1), and my problem is gone :)

Answer (score 4):

In TeXworks, special Unicode chars are inserted from the right-click menu: Right click -> Insert Unicode control character -> ZWSP Zero width space.

Comment: Thank you. **ZWNJ** solved my problem. But, is it possible to define a _shortcut key_ for that?